# UISearchBar on iPad table view disappearing below navigation controller bar

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I'm working on a Universal app, using storyboards, and I've added a `UISearchBar` and a `UISearchDisplayController` to one of my table views. I've hooked it all up, and can search fine. The problem is when I push a new view controller onto the navigation stack. On the iPhone, this is fine, but on the iPad, it results in the pushed view controller being offset underneath the navigation bar (I had to manually make the navigation bar reappear so that you could get back).

Then, when you navigate back to the original table view where the search was taking place, the search is still active, but the `UISearchBar` is now hidden behind the navigation bar, meaning there is no way to dismiss it without deleting the query. It also means that it is not longer usable, since you can't get back in to it.

Probably best illustrated using some screenshots.

Here is how it looks when you first open the tableview:

[image]

Then doing the search is fine:

[image: Doing the search is fine]

Clicking through to the next screen, we can see the issue:

[image]

And then back on the original screen, still doing the search but no search box:

[image: Search box half-buried]

Then, if I delete everything from the search box, and get rid of the overlay, I can see the search box when I scroll the table view up, but can never reach it. I can't get a reliable screen grab of that though.

I've looked everywhere for a solution but haven't been able to find one. I've tried calling `[self setNeedsDisplay]` and `[self setNeedsLayout]` in the `viewDidAppear` method, but that seems to have no effect. It seems to rectify itself if I change the orientation of the device, and I was trying to replicate what it would do in that situation by calling those methods.

The structure of the iPad storyboard is: `SplitViewController` -> Navigation Controller -> `UITabBarController` -> `UITableViewController` (contains `UISearchBar` etc.f) -> `UITableViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted this issue to Apple DTS, and they responded:

The structure of the iPad storyboard is: SplitViewController -> Navigation Controller -> UITabBarController -> UITableViewController (contains UISearchBar etc.f) -> UITableViewController

The fact is that your project architecture does not follow our guidelines which are:
From the Combined View Controller Interfaces section of the View Controller Catalog for iOS:
When combining view controllers, however, the order of containment is important; only certain arrangements are valid. The order of containment, from child to parent, is as follows:

Content view controllers, and container view controllers that have flexible bounds (such as the page view controller)
Navigation view controller
Tab bar controller
Split view controller

Basically, you should have a structure as follows:
SplitViewController -> UITabBarController ->Navigation Controller-> UITableViewController (contains UISearchBar etc.f) -> UITableViewController>

Comment: I had similar problem, fixed by changing nav bar from translucent to opaque and it suddenly started working -- that might be an ios 7 thing.

Comment: Hi Rob. I have the same problem but don't understand what you are saying here. How do I fix this?